# purple screen on boot, computer frozen

Tags: installation

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 alongside windows 8 and it worked several times when I booted the computer up to Ubuntu. However, when I tried to restart my computer today it got stuck at the purple screen that says: "error: run list overflown. press any key to continue." The cursor is not blinking and the computer is frozen. currently, my computer is stuck on that screen and I can't shut it off by holding the power button either. My machine is a Samsung series seven chronos and doesn't have a removable battery. What should I do?

Comment: can you try pressing Ctrl-Alt-F1 to go to tty mode and then login and sudo poweroff? If yes, then in next boot select safe boot option.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect your power cable. On the bottom of your notebook there should be a small hole in which you can stick a paperclip. This will poweroff your laptop. Now connect your power cable again and you should be able to boot.

---

source: https://superuser.com/questions/290132/how-to-force-power-off-of-a-samsung-series-9-laptop